# In ruby, column name refering to second table column name, cannot get second table other fields

Tags: ruby, class

I'm working with Ruby 2.7.0 to maintain an old software...

I have a table waste_types with a column `ced_code`.

I have a second table ced_codes with a column `ced_code`, and many other columns, including one, say: `label`.

From the class `WasteType`, I want to access `CedCode` data like this:

```
WasteType.ced_code_params.label
```

How to do this with ruby ?

I tried:

```
class WasteType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :ced_code_params, :foreign_key => 'ced_code', :class_name => 'CedCode'
end

class CedCode < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :waste_types, :foreign_key => 'ced_code'
end
```

I tried many things found on this forum: primary_key vs foreign_key, has_one vs belongs_to, etc.

My code `WasteType.ced_code_params.label` always cause an error: undefined method `label' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Is the `waste_types.ced_code` column NOT NULL? i.e. do you always expect to have a `CedCode` for your `WasteType`s?

Comment: Unless all of the elements along the path are guaranteed to exist, be sure to nil-guard the chain; e.g., `WasteType&.ced_code_params&.label`.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. Yes the ced_code cannot be NULL and always contains a ced_code.

Comment: If I was not under Ruby (language that I know few and dislike much because too abstracted), I would simply do a LEFT JOIN:
SELECT ced_codes.label FROM waste_types LEFT JOIN ced_codes USING (ced_code) WHERE <my conditions>...

Comment: I just managed, after 8 hours of various trials, to accidentally make it work by adding the following line to the WasteType class:
  has_one :ced_code_params, :class_name => "CedCode", :foreign_key => "ced_code", :primary_key => "ced_code"